# How to use Angular expression in an svg path element's 'd' attribute

Tags: html, angularjs, svg

I have a wavey-shaped path that needs to stretch across the screen ... it will be used as a text path for text scrolling across the screen.

In theory, to produce a sin wave across the width of the screen, it should be as simple as:

```
<div style = "position:absolute;height:3%;width:100%;top:10%;left:0;">
    <svg width='100%'  height='100%'  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <path d = "M 0 50 C 33 0, 66 100, 100 50" >
    </svg>
</div>
```

But this only gives me a very very short wave ... I guess one that is only 100pixels wide.

---

So I decided to add Angular expressions into the path definition ... (the `innerWidth` is calculated during resizing):

```
    <path id = "text_path"           
           d = "M 0 50 C {{0.33*innerWidth}} 0, {{.66*innerWidth}} 100, {{1*innerWidth}} 50"
    />
```

In firefox, Chrome, Opera35, this works great: an wave that stretches properly. But Ipad Safari, Iphone Safari,  and IE Edge, results vary in their wrongness.

**NOTE:** Chrome displays error: *Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M 0 50 C {{0.33*pvo_contMain.innerWidth}} 0, {{.66*pvo_contMain.innerWidth}} 100, {{1*pvo_contMain.innerWidth}} 50"*

**NOTE:** you can see the wave here: [test page](http://toddandd.ipower.com/shannonburnett.net/projects/braga/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK, attribute with `{{}}` is considered as to be invalid HTML for atleast `IE`. So do use `ng-attr-*` directive, which will evaluate value of interpolation `{{}}` and put it inside `d` attribute.

```
ng-attr-d="{{'M 0 50 C '+0.33*innerWidth+ '0, '+.66*innerWidth+' 100,'+ 1*innerWidth+' 50'}}"
```

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd glad to know that. Thanks :=)